# Symfony2 + FosOauth: token get, but requests are anonymous

Tags: symfony, oauth

I have installed and configurated FosOauthBundle but I have this problem: I can get Token And Refresh token with this line of code:

```
$ http POST http://localhost:8888/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/token grant_type=password client_id=1_3bcbxd9e24g0gk4swg0kwgcwg4o8k8g4g888kwc44gcc0gwwk4 client_secret=4ok2x70rlfokc8g0wws8c8kwcokw80k44sg48goc0ok4w0so0k     username=MYEMAIL     password=MYPASS
```

If I pass a wrong MYEMAIL or a wrong MYPASS symfony reply me with an error (and this is correct). Users are manged via FosUserBundle.

Now, How can I use token to say symfony that I'm a registered user ?

I have created this "api" in my controller:

```
public function getDemosAction()
    {
        $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

        $view = $this->view($user);
        return $this->handleView($view);

    }
```

and I call it via this code:

```
$curl -H "Authorization: Bearer NGEwMGIxMzJkZmU5Yjc3YmM2ZjViNmE0YWFhYTEwOTg1MjI5NzIyNDkwNmFhYTUzMTRkZTk3MzEyNjA4OWY0Ng" http://localhost:8888/app_dev.php/api/demos
```

but it return me ALWAYS "anon.".

Where is my error ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the order of firewall directives in security.yml. I have found the solution via this other question: [Symfony2 OAuth keeps giving me a login page when a token is provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542235/symfony2-oauth-keeps-giving-me-a-login-page-when-a-token-is-provided)